# Is it mandatory to kill someone for leaving Islam?

Tags: sharia, source-identification, sunnah, apostasy

There is a [similar question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/221/is-punishment-for-leaving-islam-death) on this. It is a commonly known fact that Muhammad SAWS and many caliphs punished apostasy with death.

However, my question is **whether it is *commanded* to punish someone with death for leaving Islam**.

There are many Sunnahs which are not necessarily followed, like having a beard, or cleaning teeth with siwak. The Quran has direct commandments on how to punish some crimes, like theft and adultery. But is the death penalty for apostasy merely 'good practice' or is it a commandment?

Answer (score 3):

[Indonesian - Google translate]
The scholars ('ulama) of the four madzhabs of thought agree that apostates who were under the rule of Islam and did not have the strength given a grace period for penance. If in a given period of time he still did not accept Islam, then punished kill.

However, the scholars ('ulama) differ about the time frame given.

Imam Ar Rafi'I and An Nawawi said, "apostasy is the most vile form of paganism and the harshest punishment." (In al-'Aziz Al Majmu XI/97 and' XX/369)

source : [here](http://fromjihadnews.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/pembagian-orang-murtad-dan-hukumannya/)

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the FAQ.  We would also like to recommend you look around this site to see how it works.  We also invite you to join us in [the main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819/islam) if you would like to discuss/chat with other community members.

Answer (score -5):

Allah has not put any compulsion in adopting one religion or another (http://quran.com/2/256).  He has made this world as a test (http://quran.com/67/2) and the next for its compensation. It is against His Will to kill a person, based on his religion. I believe it is against Islam to kill based on apostasy.

Comment: Please explain the reason for negative vote...

Comment: The problem with that verse is that it applies specifically to entering Islam, and not leaving. The Prophet Muhammad SAWS himself and his closest companions have killed people for apostasy, so it's not forbidden.

Comment: The verses refer to Allah's plan for this world, which is eternal. He has even told Prophet Muhammad PBUH that your job is only to convey the message clearly (http://quran.com/42/48), and not act as some guardian.

Comment: Please do provide reference for your claim and I can look into it

Comment: http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/bukhari/083-sbt.php#009.083.037 ; http://www.esinislam.com/Quran_And_Hadith/Sunan_Abu_Dawud_Hadith/Sunan_Abu_Dawud_Hadith_Book_38.htm ; http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/bukhari/084-sbt.php#009.084.058 ; Khalid al Walid killing Malik ibn Nuwayra for apostasy (al-Tabari, vol 2, pg 5)

Comment: 2.256 was abrogated or only refers to the people of the book. I think it was abrogated.