# Punishment for apostasy in Islam

Tags: apostasy, fatwa-explanation, islamqa

A few days ago I read in a website (IslamQA.com) that punishment for apostasy under sharia law is death. They also provided a hadith related to that. (the entire fatwa can be read here: http://islamqa.info/en/20824)

But doesn't this contradict the following ayah?

> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion. The right course has become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing." (Surah Al-Baqara: 256)

Please someone clear this confusion.

Comment: Related but not duplicate of [Why should a person who disbelieves after becoming Muslim be executed?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/798/why-should-a-person-who-disbelieves-after-becoming-muslim-be-executed) and [Is punishment for leaving Islam death?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/221/is-punishment-for-leaving-islam-death) & [Is it mandatory to kill someone for leaving Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/8066/11938)