# Is the belief that people who want to leave Islam should be put to death a widely held interpretation?

Tags: sharia

I am not familiar with Islam, I hear many things about it that I have to assume are biased, perhaps ignorant dramatizations of the truth. One of these things that was [said on national TV in the USA, with Bill Maher,](https://youtu.be/vln9D81eO60?t=3m10s) was that Islam teaches that members who leave Islam should be put to death.

In this discussion, Ben Affleck, a famous American actor, defends people of Islam saying there are likely very few people who believe this. I'm wondering if Islam is interpreted by many in a way that would condem. people who leave Islam to be put to death. **Is this true?** If it is only true for a small fraction on Islamist believers, how small is that fraction, and where do they get this interpretation of Islam from, specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is punishment for leaving Islam death?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/221/is-punishment-for-leaving-islam-death)

Answer (score 1):

peace be upon you, It can be proven by the following hadith, 
Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) has said: The blood of a Muslim person who bears witness that there is no God but Allah and that I 
am Allah's Messenger, is not lawful (to shed) except for one of three reasons, 
(i) a married man commits fornication, 
(ii) life for a life, and 
(iii) who abandons his religion and separates from his community. (Sunan Abu-Dawood)