# Apostasy in Islam the punishment?

Tags: fiqh, apostasy

I keep reading that non Muslims attack Islam saying one of the reasons that Islam is false is the punishment is death.

Is this true - I read a scholar saying the Prophet said those words for the people at the time for the circumstances and not meant for all places and all times to come.

Even if it is true why should it mean Islam is false?

Please help.

Comment: [The punishment for apostasy is in fact death](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/221/is-punishment-for-leaving-islam-death/), so in that far, your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Even if it is true why should it mean Islam is false?no it should not !