# Does Bulugh Al Maram Hadith Number 1242 Promote the killing of people that leave their own religion?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, apostasy

> It says Ibn 'Abbas (RA) narrated that The Messenger of Allah said, “He who changes his religion (i.e. apostates) kill him.” Related by Al-Bukhari. ([Bulugh al-Maram](https://sunnah.com/urn/2114890))

I was shocked when i saw whis, is this an authentic hadith? Can someone please explain to me why Rasulullah (SAW) said this, i want logic and context behind this Hadith since the Holy Quran has taught me that there is no compulsion in religion so im pretty confused

Comment: "Changes his religion" in this context means "changes Islam as his religion," meaning apostates from Islam. As for the details of the punishment of apostasy there are plenty of questions on the site about that.

Comment: Also see [Is punishment for leaving Islam death?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/48103/20218).

Comment: The hadith was reported in Sahih al-Bukhari and other hadith sources, while Bulugh al-Maram is just a compilation of other sources on the topic of fiqh.