# What is Shiite view on "Ali burning people"?

Tags: shiism, ali

I was reading an answer to a question on this site. Here is it : https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/254/51089

The answer states that Ali burnt some people for a reason as :

> It is related from ‘Ikrima that ‘Ali burnt some people and that reached Ibn ‘Abbas who said, “If it had been me, I would not have burned them because the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, ‘Do not punish with Allah’s punishment.’ I would have killed them as the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, ‘If someone changes his religion, kill him.’”

Is this considered un-authentic by Shia scholars in common ?

P.S.- I'm asking this because it is very opposite and contradictory to the character of Ali that I have read of. Further, I asked a nearby twelver Maulana about this and he refused that Ali can do so; thus, mentioning it as fabricated or for insulting his character. He said that burning alive people had never been a part of Islam (consequently, mentioning that it's a very low, immoral and unjustified form of punishment).

Comment: Please quote the relevant parts of the linked thread. Questions need to be able to stand alone, otherwise they risk losing all of their value if/when the link ever dies or changes.

Comment: @goldPseudo Ok thanks. I'll do it immediately.